# Spring data jpa projection could not extract ResultSet

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to map my entity to projection using the below query but i'm getting error as

> Exception : could not extract ResultSet SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

here is the query

```java
@Query("select rf.rfqID as rfqID,rf.creationDate as creationDate," +
   "rf.deadLineDate as deadLineDate,rf.details as details," +
   "rf.message as message, rf.rfqDoc as rfqDoc," +
   "CASE WHEN (rf.creationDate > CURRENT_DATE) THEN 'open' ELSE 'closed' END as status," +
   "rf.rfqMembers as rfqMembers " +
   "from RFQ rf where rf.createdBy = ?1")
Page<RfqDto> loadAllRfq(String creator, Pageable pageable);
```

In my Dto I have an extra status column which I don't want to persist in db and would like to get the status via query

here is my projection interface

```java
public interface RfqDto {
    String rfqID();
    Date creationDate();
    Date deadLineDate();
    String details();
    String message();
    String rfqDoc();
    String status();
    List<RfqMember> rfqMembers();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The root cause of your problem is here:

> In my Dto I have an extra status column which I don't want to persist in db and would like to get the status via query

As it's explained in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections):

> The important bit here is that the properties defined here exactly match properties in the aggregate root.
> ...
> *The query execution engine creates proxy instances of that interface at runtime for each element returned and forwards calls to the exposed methods to the target object.*

So, you can not use spring data jpa projection for your case. You can not use [hibernate/jpa projection](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-select-clause) as well, because it dose not  support collections in row results.

You can try to use [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage). See for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67407045/6277104).