# JPA Projection @OneToMany not working 'Unable to locate appropriate constructor'

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, projection

I have a large entity-class with many, many fields and a projection-class which should be a part of the large one.

Everything works fine, except the @OneToMany field. The @OneToMany field should be a list of addresses, but when converting it to the projection-class I always get the error "Unable to locate appropriate constructor [...] Expected arguments are: long, [...], ***.entity.Address".

The converter is searching for a single address Object instead of a List of Address Objects, and I don't understand why. I use lombok @Data and @AllArgsConstructor, so Getter and Setter should be there.

```
@Entity
@Data
public class House implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", precision = 5)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "HouseID")
    private List<Address> identAdressen;
}

/// ----------------
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class HouseView {
    private Long objnr;
    private List<Address> identAdressen;
}
```

When I remove the "List" in the HouseView-class it works as long as there are only single addresses, but when there are multiple it crashes too.

I don't get it why he tries to find a HouseView-Constructor with an single address-object, when in both classes there are Lists of Addresses.

Comment: JPA expects a @NoArgsConstructor too.

Comment: Then I get "No converter found capable of converting from type House to HouseView"

Comment: @J-Eibe hibernate projections do not support collections in result set, see for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67488816/6277104).

Answer (score 0):

Let trying not using lombok and see if it works

Comment: Writing contructor, getter and setter by myself does not change anything :/

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data Projections do not support collections but I think this is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(House.class)
public interface HouseView {
    @IdMapping
    Long getObjnr();
    Set<AddressView> getIdentAddressen();

    @EntityView(Address.class)
    interface AddressView {
        @IdMapping
        Long getId();
        String getName();
    }
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`HouseView a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, HouseView.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

```
Page<HouseView> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

The best part is, it will only fetch the state that is actually necessary!

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to write custom query on HouseRepository as
`@Query("SELECT new com.packagename.HouseView(hos) from House hos")`
then house view class can be as follows

```
public class HouseView {
    private Long objnr;
    private List<Address> identAdressen;
    public HouseView(House house) {
         identAdressen = house.identAdressen;
    }
}
```

Hope it will work :) You can add more fields into constructor from join tables if required. It might help others coming late on post.